# Why does Sakurai's book use the gyromagnetic ratio of the electron as $\frac{e}{m_e c}$ instead of $\frac{e}{m_e}$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, angular-momentum

I'm studying quantum computing, but I had to review some concepts in supplementary readings, where I came across the following question about a simple detail: Why does Sakurai's book (near Eq. 1.1) use the gyromagnetic ratio of the electron as $\frac{e}{m_e c}$ instead of simply $\frac{e}{m_e}$? Does it have anything to do with the CGS system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CGS units have an extra $c$ in the denominator when compared to SI units, [for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_magneton):

[image]